# Informix "no such DBspace" error when inserting a record

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, db2, informix

I am getting the error when attempting to run an insert against an Informix database ("DB2 v10.5.700.375 Fix Pack 7"), using .NET Entity Framework 6.1.3

```
ERROR [IX000] [IBM][IDS/NT64] Invalid default sbspace name (sbspace). (-130 ISAM error: no such DBspace)
```

This page http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21424434 suggested checking the onstat command.

The output of the "onstat -d" command is:

```
C:\Program Files\Informix>onstat -d

IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 12.10.FC9DE -- On-Line -- Up 1 days 22:26:52 -- 185088 Kbytes

Dbspaces
address          number   flags      fchunk   nchunks  pgsize   flags    owner    name
0000000080CD5030 1        0x30001    1        1        4096     N  BA    informix rootdbs
 1 active, 2047 maximum

Chunks
address          chunk/dbs     offset     size       free       bpages     flags pathname
0000000080CD5280 1      1      0          216064     91351                 PO-B-D C:\PROGRA~1\Informix\storage\rootdbs.000
 1 active, 32766 maximum

NOTE: The values in the "size" and "free" columns for DBspace chunks are
      displayed in terms of "pgsize" of the DBspace to which they belong.


Expanded chunk capacity mode: always
```

Comment: See connectionstrings.  I believe you are not specifying the correct database.  The server is correct but you are not indicating which database on the server you are using either in the connection string or in you query.  See : https://www.connectionstrings.com/informix/

Comment: Good call on showing the output from `onstat -d`; that made the problem diagnosis straight-forward.  Thank you.

Comment: Why is your Informix database called "DB2 v10.5.700.375 Fix Pack 7"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of `onstat -d` shows you have a regular dbspace called `rootdbs`; it does not show any sbspaces at all, let alone one named `sbspace`.  An sbspace (smart blob space) is used to store smart blobs.  Your system is configured to expect/use an sbspace called `sbspace`.  And whatever it is you are inserting needs to be stored in an sbspace.  It might be a BLOB or CLOB value, or it might be another type that uses smart blobs for the storage mechanism.

You need to create a file (or choose a disk device) to use for the sbspace, and then add it.

You're on Windows, it seems.  There are probably other ways of doing what I'm about to do the Unix-like way.  As user `informix`, do:

```
cd C:\PROGRA~1\Informix\storage
cp nul: sbspace.000
onspaces -c -S sbspace -p C:\PROGRA~1\Informix\storage\sbspace.000 -o 0 -s 10240
```

The `-c` means 'create'; the `-S sbspace` means 'create an sbspace called `sbspace`; the `-p` specifies the full path of the file; the `-o 0` specifies that the offset should be 0; the `-s 10240` sets the size to 10 MiB.

By all means make the size bigger; how much bigger depends on how much data you're going to store in the smart blob space, which in turn depends on what your inserting and how many of them you're going to insert and how big each one is.

The offset of zero is a hangover from the 'bad old days' when disk drives were not as big as 2 GiB (they've grown over the last 30 years!).  Assume the offset will always be zero (but the system demands that you specify zero, rather than defaulting it to zero) unless you're using raw disk (which you aren't with the commands shown).  And the argument sequence for `-p`, `-o`, `-s` matters too.

You should do an archive of the system after adding the sbspace.

If you need more space in future, you can add more chunks to the existing sbspace.

You can find more options by running `onspaces` as `informix` with no other options; it shows what else you can specify.

You can find the manual pages for `onspaces` in the IBM Knowledge Centre:

- [`onspaces`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.adref.doc/ids_adr_0460.htm)

Comment: Yep there was in insert into a CLOB field.